# How to run a simple DNS Proxy Server like CloudFlare?

Tags: linux, dns

Suppose the following situations: `doamin1.com`, `domain2.com` and `domain3.com`, and `server1`, `server2`, `server3` and `server4`.

What I want to have is simple servers like CloudFlare, that DNSs are pointed to two different servers, but the actual server is the third one which the end user cannot see that.

Like CF, when you enable Cloud and ping domain, you'll see CF's IP.

I want to have this, but want to proxy all DNSs. I mean I edit Bind manually in SSH.

Is there anyway to do this in simple? Or requires more servers and techs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a "DNS proxy" – it's an HTTP reverse-proxy.

Even though in CF you activate it through the DNS control panel, it has very little to do with DNS proxying; enabling the "cloud" button just completely removes your real server from DNS and replaces it with the IP addresses of CF's reverse-proxy servers.

So in order to do this yourself, you'll also need to set up an "HTTP reverse proxy" server – there are plenty of options, e.g. HAproxy/Nginx/Traefik/Caddy are commonly used for reverse-proxying. (Even Apache httpd with "ProxyPass" could also work for small sites.)

Once you have a reverse-proxy server set up, just edit DNS to point all domains to the proxy server's IP address instead of the real web server.

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot I can do it with reverse proxying.